# If $M$ is a compact oriented parallelizable 4 dimensional manifold, then it admits a flat metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, characteristic-classes

In order to prove that the first Pontryagin class of the tangent space of a compact oriented parallelizable 4 dimensional manifold is zero, my Professor suggested me to prove that such hypothesis imply that $M$ admits a flat metric and then $p_1(TM)$ will be zero since it is equal to $c_2(TM\otimes \mathbb{C})$ (second Chern class).  I couldn't managed to prove this statement, buy already proved that $p_1(TM) = 0$ since in this case $c_2(TM\otimes \mathbb{C})$ will be de Euler class of the tangent space and $e(TM)$ is zero because $M$ is parallelizable. I would like to know how to prove that $M$ admits a flat metric, so I hope someone can help me. I would also be grateful if someone gives me a concrete example of a manifold in which this happens.

Comment: The fact that the first Pontryagin class of a parallelisable manifold is trivial follows immediately from the definition. In particular, if $\varepsilon_{\mathbb{R}}^k$ denotes the trivial rank $k$ real vector bundle, then for $i > 0$, we have $p_i(\varepsilon^k) = (-1)^ic_{2i}(\varepsilon^k\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}) = (-1)^ic_{2i}(\varepsilon^k_{\mathbb{C}}) = 0$ where $\varepsilon^k_{\mathbb{C}}$ denotes the trivial rank $k$ complex vector bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not. The simplest example is to take any closed oriented 3-manifold $N$ (for instance, $S^3$) and multiply it by the circle. The resulting manifold $M$ is parallelizable (since every orientable 3-manifold is) but admits a flat metric if and only if $N$ admits a flat metric.